# Manipular elementos de um iframe

Tags: javascript, html

eu tenho uma página, por exemplo, index.html e form.html

A pagina index.html tem um iframe, que carrega a form.html

A pergunta é: pela pagina index.html, eu posso via JS submeter um form, que esta dentro do meu iframe?

Ou seja, consigo manipular estes elementos?

Eu preciso disso para fins de testes e aprendizado.

Obrigada

Comment: A página `form.html` está no mesmo dominio que `index.html`?

Comment: Não, ela esta em outro dominio.

Comment: Nesse caso o Browser proíbe isso por questões de segurança...